# Fetching Core Data entities with Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I've been struggling with this all afternoon. I can do this in Obj-C in my sleep but I can't seem to grasp what I am suppose to do in Swift. I can get an array of entities back (StoredTopic) but I keep getting errors trying to access them.

Here's the fetch code:

```
func fetchCoreData(_ entityName:String) -> [NSManagedObject] {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return []
    }

    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest =
        NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)

    do {

        let arrData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    return []
}
```

Here's the log of arrData

```
[<StoredTopic: 0x6040000833e0> (entity: StoredTopic; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://C27694CF-4EB0-4F28-8D7D-4DFFAA1051A4/StoredTopic/p1> ; data: <fault>), <StoredTopic: 0x604000085960> (entity: StoredTopic; id: 0xd000000000080000 <x-coredata://C27694CF-4EB0-4F28-8D7D-4DFFAA1051A4/StoredTopic/p2> ; data: <fault>), <StoredTopic: 0x604000083020> (entity: StoredTopic; id: 0xd0000000000c0000 <x-coredata://C27694CF-4EB0-4F28-8D7D-4DFFAA1051A4/StoredTopic/p3> ; data: <fault>), <StoredTopic: 0x604000088de0> (entity: StoredTopic; id: 0xd000000000100000 <x-coredata://C27694CF-4EB0-4F28-8D7D-4DFFAA1051A4/StoredTopic/p4> ; data: <fault>), <StoredTopic: 0x60000008c580> (entity: StoredTopic; id: 0xd000000000140000 <x-coredata://C27694CF-4EB0-4F28-8D7D-4DFFAA1051A4/StoredTopic/p5> ; data: {
createDt = "2017-11-02 19:28:00 +0000";
segObj = 0;
segTopic = 0;
title = Test;
topicID = "4A55582B-3084-4ECA-8F61-C1193A85B45B";
"topic_desc" = 1234567890;
updateDt = "2017-11-02 19:28:00 +0000";
```

So if I try to do something like:

arrData[0].topicID I get **"Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'topicID'"**

If I try to do like some other SO post suggested by adding this line:

```
var arrStoredTopic = [StoredTopic]()
arrStoredTopic = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
```

I get **"Cannot assign value of type '[NSManagedObject]' to type '[StoredTopic]'"**

I then tried to follow this tutorial, though it was a little outdated with some of the calls and changed my code to follow it:

```
func fetchCoreData(_ entityName:String) -> [NSManagedObject] {

    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return []
    }

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: managedContext)
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    do {

        //let arrData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

        if results.count > 0 {

            let storedData = results[0] as! NSManagedObject

        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }

    return []
}
```

Still not able to access the StoredTopic properties.

So how do I fetch managedObjects from Core Data so I can work with them? I'm obviously confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: entityName)
```

to

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<StoredTopic>(entityName: entityName)
```

or

```
let fetchRequest = StoredTopic.fetchRequest()
```

In your original code you are saying the fetch request will fetch `NSManagedObject`s not `StoredTopic`s and that is why you are having issues with accessing properties and assigning the results of the fetch request to a `[StoredTopic]`.

Swift is a type safe language so it is very strict about things that Objective-C doesn't worry about (until it crashes at runtime).

Comment: Oh God, I know, it's driving me nuts. Owe you a beer. :)

Comment: You'll get the hang of it in time, I started with Objective-C before there was such a thing as iPhones and managed to get it. It mostly comes down to making sure you tell the compiler _exactly_ what things are.

Comment: So did I, I was building desktop apps for a publishing company, then the phone came out and made that transition. I don't have formal comp-sci training, Obj-c was really my first language so sometimes it's an uphill struggle...but thanks. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Glad to be of help.